# shinyR - Dynamically Reference Input Field Value via Text

Tags: r, user-interface, dynamic, shiny, tags

I have constructed an input form with many, many input fields.

I want to reference each of these fields, by using a for loop statement, dynamically generating the tag as text, and having shiny treat it as a tag name (rather than typing out hundreds of calls to each field).

I'm fine with building a loop statement, the problem, is that I don't know how to explicitly reference a shiny input field - without of course typing input$fieldname.

Is there a method I can explicitly convert the text "input$fieldname" to instead reference the value of a shiny input field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically reference an input like this:

```
input[['mytextbox']]
```

So if you have the string "input$mytextbox", you can get its value like this:

```
mystring <- "input$mytextbox" 
input[[substring(mystring, 7)]]
```

Here is a minimal working example

```
library(shiny)

mystring <- "input$mytextbox" 

ui <- fluidPage(
  
    textInput('mytextbox', 'My Text Box', value = 'Hello World'),
    actionButton('mybutton', 'Dynamically Get Value')
    
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    observeEvent(input$mybutton, {

        showNotification(
            
            input[[substring(mystring, 7)]]
            
        )
 
    })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The amount of rabbit holes I went down...
Last question... why do we use the argument of 7 within substring?

Comment: We use 7, as we want from the 7th character onward from our string input$mytextbox", i.e. we just want the 'mytextbox' bit, and not the 'input$' bit.

Comment: One more question Ash.... is there a special method to reference an input object with multiple levels? E.g. input$fileUpload$name - I'm currently struggling with this at the moment...

Comment: Found my answer - an extra pair of double square brackets on the end:
input[[substring(mystring,7)]][[1]]